# How do I make my stored procedure ask for values every time I call it

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new in MySql/Oracle and I'm trying to write a procedure that asks for 2 values, compares them and returns the big one, but I'm having trouble by the time I try to call it.

Here's my code for the creation of the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NUMAYOR AS
   Num1 int;
   Num2 int;
BEGIN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ingrese el primer número:');
   Num1 := TO_NUMBER(&VAR1);
   
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ingrese el segundo número:');
   Num2 := TO_NUMBER(&VAR2);
   IF Num1 > Num2 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Num1 || ' es mayor que ' || Num2);
   ELSIF Num2 > Num1 THEN 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Num2 || ' es mayor que ' || Num1);
   ELSE 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Los números son iguales, por favor introduce dos números diferentes');
   END IF;
END;
```

This works well but when I call the procedure again with

```
BEGIN 
    NUMAYOR;
END;
```

The console returns me the numbers I entered on the stored procedure but I want to ask again for new numbers every time I execute it.

I would appreciate if someone help me with this, I feel that is easier than I think but I tried a lot of things and I can't find the solution.

Sorry for my English - I'm Spanish so don't judge me too much

Comment: MySQL or OracleDB? These are two absolutely different DBMSs..

Comment: The code executed at the DBMS side is not interactive. It is entirely remote, so you cannot interact with users from the DBMS side. Build this login in the app and pass that values to the procedure

Comment: Note that PL/SQL is not designed to build fully interactive front-end application user interfaces. It is more for the construction of data manipulation APIs to support *other* front-end interface languages that aren't designed for data access or manipulation. Some utilities like SQLPlus allow you to create prompts for substitution variables in scripts, but these abilities are specific to the client tool, not the PL/SQL language, and are generally only used for things like installation or other administrative scripts, and not for end-users.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, no - you don't want to do it that way.

What you need is a **function** that returns desired result. Here's an example which shows one way to do that:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION numayor (num1 IN NUMBER, num2 IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5     RETURN GREATEST (num1, num2);
  6  END;
  7  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT numayor (-1, 8) res1, numayor (0, 4) res2, numayor (5, 9) res3 FROM DUAL;

      RES1       RES2       RES3
---------- ---------- ----------
         8          4          9

SQL>
```

Therefore, any time you want to use it, simply call the function, pass two parameters and that's it. Certainly, you can improve that code (what to do if parameter(s) aren't passed to function (i.e. you pass `null`), etc.).

---

Procedure you created asked for values of substitution variables and created procedure with values you provided, and that's it - no future changes are possible, unless you (again) create or **replace** procedure with new code/values.

Have a look at what your code is doing:

```
Create procedure; I'm being asked to provide two values:

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NUMAYOR AS
  2     Num1 int;
  3     Num2 int;
  4  BEGIN
  5
  6     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ingrese el primer número:');
  7     Num1 := TO_NUMBER(&VAR1);
  8
  9     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ingrese el segundo número:');
 10     Num2 := TO_NUMBER(&VAR2);
 11     IF Num1 > Num2 THEN
 12        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Num1 || ' es mayor que ' || Num2);
 13     ELSIF Num2 > Num1 THEN
 14        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Num2 || ' es mayor que ' || Num1);
 15     ELSE
 16        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Los números son iguales, por favor introduce dos números diferentes');
 17     END IF;
 18  END;
 19  /
Enter value for var1: 2
old   7:    Num1 := TO_NUMBER(&VAR1);
new   7:    Num1 := TO_NUMBER(2);
Enter value for var2: 6
old  10:    Num2 := TO_NUMBER(&VAR2);
new  10:    Num2 := TO_NUMBER(6);

Procedure created.
```

If I execute it, it always returns the same result:

```
SQL> exec numayor
Ingrese el primer número:
Ingrese el segundo número:
6 es mayor que 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec numayor
Ingrese el primer número:
Ingrese el segundo número:
6 es mayor que 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Why? Have a look at procedure's code. I marked lines which show that the same values are used, **always**:

```
SQL> select text from user_source where name = 'NUMAYOR';

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCEDURE NUMAYOR AS
   Num1 int;
   Num2 int;
BEGIN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ingrese el primer número:');
   Num1 := TO_NUMBER(2);                                     --> here

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ingrese el segundo número:');
   Num2 := TO_NUMBER(6);                                     --> here
   IF Num1 > Num2 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Num1 || ' es mayor que ' || Num2);
   ELSIF Num2 > Num1 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Num2 || ' es mayor que ' || Num1);
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Los números son iguales, por favor introduce dos números diferentes');
   END IF;
END;

18 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Therefore, no - you don't want to do it that way. If it must be a procedure, then

- declare two `in` parameters (as my function does)
- create one `out` parameter (which will be the result)
- any time you call it, you'll have to use PL/SQL block as you'll have to put that `out` parameter's value *somewhere*
- note that `dbms_output.put_line` calls are visible only to tools that support them (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD and such. Oracle Apex, Forms and similar applications will *ignore* it and you won't see any result).

Something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE numayor (num1 IN NUMBER, num2 IN NUMBER, result OUT NUMBER)
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4     result := GREATEST (num1, num2);
  5  END;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_result  NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4     numayor (1, 8, l_result);
  5     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_result);
  6  END;
  7  /
8

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you really, Really, REALLY want to be asked for values, use anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (GREATEST (&num1, &num2));
  3  END;
  4  /
Enter value for num1: 1
Enter value for num2: 5
5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for num1: -2
Enter value for num2: 7
7

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Just why create a function when just select GREATEST (&num1, &num2) from dual will do? Only for a school homework would one create such a procedure or function.

Comment: Exactly, @Bogdan. Someone - who is new at this - will try a lot of things, including ones that can be done differently and more efficiently. But, if you don't try it, how will you learn anything?

Answer (score 0):

So, substitution variables - those prefixed with & - are specific for sqlplus and for other PL/SQL IDE (like sqldeveloper, pl/sql developer, TOAD), but are not to be used in PL/SQL in stored procedures. A procedure should have parameters. And, on call from your IDE (sqlplus or other) for the params should be substitution variables.
Thus, your procedure should be like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NUMAYOR(num1 number, num2 number) AS
  Num1 int;
  Num2 int;
BEGIN

  IF Num1 > Num2 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Num1 || ' es mayor que ' || Num2);
  ELSIF Num2 > Num1 THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Num2 || ' es mayor que ' || Num1);
  ELSE 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Los números son iguales, por favor introduce dos números diferentes');
  END IF;
END;
```

And the procedure call should be:

```
begin
  NUMAYOR(&num1, &num2);
end;
/
```

But, the procedure you wrote does what the SQL function greatest does, only that greatest is even better, for it admits more than two parameters.
Moreover: beware of dbms_output. That actually writes to a buffer that admits no more than 1000000 characters. And the contents of that buffer is displayed in dbms_output capable IDE-s only after the procedure completes. If some unhandled exception occurs, then you will not see anything from dbms_output.
dbms_output is not to be used in applications developed in Java or .NET or Python or some other... dbms_output is pretty good only for debugging purposes - I say pretty good, but often times not good enough...

Comment: "A procedure should have parameters" Why? For instance you could have a procedure that remove some records that are older than a year. Well, of course, one could define the "older limit" as a configurable parameter, but, if we are absolutely sure that this value will never need to be varied, then the parameter is unnecessary. Imagine a cron job executing a stored procedure for cleanup purposes.